# Use the same function to map different arrays in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, draggable

I'm trying to use the [vuedraggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) component and to "nest" it.

I'm fetching data from one table, that fetches data from the second and the second from the third (you get the point). And the second and third table is the ones that I'm currently interested in being able to change the order of.

I have a column named `order` (yeah, should have chosen `sorted_order` or something else). But for the moment I'm having problems to "reuse" the mapping function. I don't want to different functions, that doesn't seem to be the right way of doing it..

So for the first one, it looks like this:

```
<draggable v-if="stacksData.length" :element="'ul'" v-model="stacksData" :options="{animation: 150, handle:'.handle'}" @start="drag=true" @end="drag=false" @change="update">
        <li v-for="(stack, index) in stacksData">
            <i class="fas fa-arrows-alt handle"></i> <button v-on:click="fetchQuestions(stack)" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">{{ stack.name }} ({{ stack.question_count }}) (order {{ stack.order }})</button>
        </li>
    </draggable>
```

And the second one:

```
    <draggable v-if="questionsData.length" :element="'ul'" v-model="questionsData" :options="{animation: 150, handle:'.handle'}" @start="drag=true" @end="drag=false">
        <li v-if="questionsData.length" v-for="(question, index) in questionsData">
            <i class="fas fa-arrows-alt handle"></i> {{ question.description }} (order {{ question.order }})
        </li>
    </draggable>
```

My "update" function, as it is just now:

```
    update(event){
        console.log(event)
        this.stacksData.map((stacksData, index) => {
            stacksData.order = index + 1
        })
    }
```

Expected result:
Be able to call the update function on any array containing column `order` and update the order of it.

Comment: [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array. Maybe you want to reassign the data like `this.stacksData = this.stacksData.map(...)` or better yet, use a `computed` property. Or if you simply need to update the `order`, why not use a `forEach` loop?

Comment: @Adam Did you try my answer ?